# To what extent can buying/selling shares be computerised?

Tags: scripting

Out of interest, how far can buying and selling shares be made automatic? How far do you think it can go? And what would you need to do it?

Comment: This question is very unclear, and seems to be off-topic. If you have a specific programming question, we can assist you.

Comment: How does this anyway relates to `scripting`? Your question doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Very far.

There are real computers [performing fully automated trades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_trading) as we type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at some trading APIs provided by E*TRADE https://us.etrade.com/e/t/activetrading/api or something similar. You can use virtually any language to call the API and execute trades, get quotes, and generate strategic algorithms.

However, a fair warning, unless you are a large corporation with lots of money to burn you need to be careful as a homegrown algorithmic trading system can be very dangerous.

I believe something like 70% of all trades on the market today are placed by computer systems automatically and not by people. It makes it harder for smaller individuals to compete because we simply don't have the financial resources to purchase the power and speed we need to compete.

Thanks,
Jeffrey Pry